# Celery task in which need to update field after 1 month pass after creation

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, celery, django-celery

Idea is create celery task, in which after 1 month from creation (**created_at** field)
update price field with 5% discount.

**Model:**

```
class Product(models.Model):
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=2,
                                help_text="Current price of products")
    old_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=2,
                                    help_text="Old price of products", null=True, blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
```

Comment: Why update the field, and not just write some logic that checks if the current date is passed `created_at`, and in that case apply the discount.

Answer (score 1):

@Willem suggested quite a good approach but if you still want to update the field itself, then you can use a celery task that runs daily. In this way, you don't have to run a celery task for each product instance but rather a periodic celery task that runs once a day and checks all the products and applies the discount to the ones created exactly 30 days ago:

```
from datetime import timedelta
from django.utils import timezone


@task
def apply_discount():
    Product.objects.filter(
        created__lte=timezone.now() - timedelta(days=30),
        created__gt=timezone.now() - timedelta(days=31)
    ).update(price=F('price') * Decimal('0.95'))
```

Then register the task in your settings file:

```
CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'apply-discount': {
        'task': 'app.tasks.apply_discount',
        'schedule': crontab(hour=1, minute=0),
    }
}
```

This runs the task at 1 am daily

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making a celery task, you can write some logic that checks if the current date is passed `created_at`, and in that case apply the discount. For example with the [**`dateutil`** package [readthedocs]](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/):

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
from django.utils.timezone import now
from decimal import Decimal

class Product(models.Model):
    price = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=15,
        decimal_places=2,
        help_text='Current price of products'
    )
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)

    @property
    def real_price(self):
        if created_at + relativedelta(month=1) < now():
            return self.price * Decimal('0.95')
        return self.price
```

or we can work with an annotation:

```
from django.utils.timezone import now
from django.db.models import Case, DecimalField, F, Value, When
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
from decimal import Decimal

Product.objects.annotate(
    real_price=Case(
        When(
            created_at__lt=now() - relativedelta(month=1),
            then=F('price') * Decimal('0.95')
        ),
        default=F('price'),
        output_field=DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=2)
    )
)
```

Here the `Product`s that arise from the queryset have an extra attribute `.real_price` that is thus a discounted one after a month.